# Laravel Redirect to an url and submit form on page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect

For an application in Laravel, I need a solution for this matter:

I'm looking for a way to go to an external url and on this website there is a (authentication) form for login. 
i want to redirect to this external url and fill in this form and submit it automatically. This without any user interaction.

an example: 
I redirect to https://google.com and the application fills in my account and password automatically. And submits this form also.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect()->with();
```

Use this function and send data redirect url and get data and save database

Comment: Please provide more information. This reads as a comment rather than a full answer.

Comment: use curl to submit form  for heple you follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138534/3972403 this answer

Comment: @ShofiullahBabor This might lead to a solution, I think

Answer (score 0):

Just add your value with "with()" function...

```
return redirect("google.com")->with([
           "account" => $value, "password" => $value2 
       ]);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem... I need to submit the form on the external website, this only fills in the form

Comment: Then I think your question description is not enough information.. You can describe your problem with more detail. Then I might i help you.

Comment: If you want to submit an external form , then you need to know to how that form work or how that action page work... You need  to submit proper variable.. Can you provide me that external form action page detail..?